# DotnetHighCharts - Multiple Charts positioned on one page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnethighcharts

I have to display 3 charts, as part of a dashboard, on one page.

The dotnetHighCharts demo project does include a "How to" for multiple charts.
This however seems to assume that the charts will simply be placed below each other.
My View has quite a bit of html formatting where I want to render the charts in containers.

So in my Controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        Highcharts chartLine = Chart_Line();
        Highcharts chartPie = Chart_Pie();

        return View(new Container(new[] { chartLine, chartPie }));
    }
```

But instead of simply having this in my View:

```
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Container

@(Model)
```

I have to place the specific the charts on specific locations of my page.
So in my view I would have liked to do something like @(Model[1]) to display to display the 1st chart etc.

I also tried creating a viewmodel:

```
public class ChartsModel
{
    public Highcharts Chart1 { get; set; }
    public Highcharts Chart2 { get; set; }
    public Highcharts Chart3 { get; set; }
}
```

Hoping that I would be able to do this in my View:

```
<div> @model.Chart1 </div>
```

But that also doesn't seem possible.

Anyway I can display multiple DotNetHighCharts on one page, while keeping control where to place them in the View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    //NOTE: chart names must be unique!
    Highcharts chartLine = Chart_Line();
    Highcharts chartPie = Chart_Pie();
    Highcharts chartColumn = Chart_Column();

    var charts = new ChartsModel
    {
        Chart1 = chartLine,
        Chart2 = chartPie,
        Chart3 = chartColumn 
    }

    return View(charts);
}
```

**View**

```
@model ChartsModel

<div>@Model.Chart1</div>
<div>@Model.Chart2</div>
<div>@Model.Chart3</div>
```

in your `Chart_Line()` method, when you create the Highcharts , you should set the unique name of chart ,

for example:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("uniqueId")
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the strange behavior I get when I do that;  Using only 2 charts at this stage.
When I add chart1 to my view, it works. When I add chart2, it for some reason displays chart2 where the 1ste chart should be displayed and nothing on the location of chart2 (chart1 is not displayed at all). And if I only add chart2 to the View, it displays that chart as it should. Any idea why it would act so strange when both are added to the View?

Comment: in your `Chart_Line()` method, when you create the `Highcharts` , you should set the unique name of chart , for exam: `Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("uniqueId")`

Comment: Share your `Chart_Line()` and `Chart_Pie()` methods content, please.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem, I didn't realize the methods should also use unique chart ids